# Micronaut version upgrade to 3.4.0 is throwing java VerifyError

Tags: java, upgrade, java-11, micronaut

I am using micronaut version 3.3.3, application/library version 3.2.1, and micronaut data processor version 3.2.2 (why explicit mention? Long story, probably unrelated) with multi module gradle structure with java 11.

When I try to upgrade to micronaut version 3.4.0 without any change in any other dependency, it fails with the following error.

Then I tried to upgrade everything to the latest (3.6.1) and with java 11 and 17 both. I am facing the same error.

It feels like the java version compilation could be the issue but I am not able to pinpoint anything. Everything seems to have the latest of everything. Also even without java upgrade, it is throwing error!

Unfortunately, I won't be able to upload the sample code as it is. Any insights will be helpful.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    insurance/$InsuranceContract$Introspection.dispatch(ILjava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @28: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'insurance/$InsuranceContract$Introspection' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'io/micronaut/context/AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @28
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'insurance/$InsuranceContract$Introspection', integer, 'java/lang/Object', '[Ljava/lang/Object;' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object', 'insurance/$InsuranceContract$Introspection', integer }
  Bytecode:
```

Comment: Can you please create a reproducer and submit an issue?

Comment: That's the detail I added in original question, I won't be able to submit the code. I am posting the question because the error seems to be generic, not related to micronaut per se. So I might be missing any general Java gotcha.

Comment: It looks like Micronaut related; maybe you can extract `InsuranceContract` to a simple project, and if it does the same error, report an issue.